# Syntax for purging multiple files at a time?

Tags: netdna-api

I seem to have purging one file at a time working by using file=/common/filetopurge.js but how do I go about purging multiple in the same DELETE request if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2200550 If you send the files in an Array our API will purge all files in parallel.  Hope that helps.  If not let me know.